# Align right with 2 inline divs?

Tags: css, html, alignment, inline

I have a problem with 2 inline divs.

I have something like this (display: inline):

```
DIV1 DIV2
```

with text.

I'd like:

```
DIV 1 -------------------- DIV2 (aligned right: 60px).
```

I couldn't do it, **right** property isn't making effect.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/tyfNx/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` on your `.welcomeText` class:

```
.welcomeText {
    text-align: right;
    right: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}​
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/tyfNx/1/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Damn I tried with fixed lol, thanks a lot.

thats working now!

Comment: Yes I was waiting the minutes but went to lunch before I could accept.